# Web/CSS: Pixel perfect/cleartype font

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, pixel

I have a pixel font (i.e. at size 10px the characters are exactly made of 1 pixel wide parts). I use it inside my web page but the font is not rendered pixel-perfect and there seems to be a cleartype issue (I think that's how it's called?). By that I mean red/blue pixels hanging around even though the font color is pure white. You can see it in the pictures below.

Two screenshots will help you understand my problem:

I currently have this on my html page (rendered in Chrome):

[image: Got this]

But I want this:

[image: Expected this]

As you can see in the first picture, even though all the text blocks are all spans with the same css behind it, they don't look the same depending on their position in the page (I guess it's because they are placed in a float position instead of an integer, so 1 pixel looks like ~1.5).

Note: the font is currently imported with `@font-face` in `.woff2` and `.woff` formats, in that order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a font that works great for me: https://www.dafont.com/fr/pixel-operator.font.

I have to carefully place html elements to avoid positioning them with floating-point numbers positions, but it's the most consistent font I found so far.